# Conditionally loading a storyboard file and the first scene from the AppDelegate

Tags: ios5, xcode4.5, uistoryboard, appdelegate

I recently converted my app to a universal binary, and I duplicated my existing storyboard to one formatted for the iPad.  I am under the impression I can conditionally load a storyboard file from the method,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

I have the following code in the above method, but my initial scene is not loading from the storyboard file.  I am getting a white screen with nothing in it, but I do see the status bar.

```
// iPad Legacy 1024 x 768
    if([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        // the iOS device is in the iPad family.


        NSLog(@"the iOS device = %@",[UIDevice currentDevice]);

        CGSize iOSDeviceScreenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

        NSLog(@"The size of screen is %f",iOSDeviceScreenSize.height);

            if (iOSDeviceScreenSize.height == 1024) {

                // load storyboard , load rootviewcontroller, show initial scene

                UIStoryboard *sbipad = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPad" bundle:nil];

                ViewControllerWelcome *vcwelcome = [sbipad instantiateInitialViewController];

                self.window.rootViewController = vcwelcome;

                [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

                NSLog(@"iPad storyboard file loaded");
            }
    }

    if([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {

        CGSize iOSDeviceScreenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

            if (iOSDeviceScreenSize.height == 480) {

                // iphone 3GS, 4, 4S, and iPod Touch 3rd and 4th gen 3.5 inch screen diagnolly measured

                UIStoryboard *sbiphone = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone" bundle:nil];

                ViewControllerWelcome *vcwelcome = [sbiphone instantiateInitialViewController];

                self.window.rootViewController = vcwelcome;

                [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

                NSLog(@"iPhone storyboard file loaded");
            }

            if (iOSDeviceScreenSize.height == 568) {

                // iphone 5 and ipod touch 5th gen: 4 inch screen diagnolly measured

                UIStoryboard *sbiphone = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone" bundle:nil];

                ViewControllerWelcome *vcwelcome = [sbiphone instantiateInitialViewController];

                self.window.rootViewController = vcwelcome;

                [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

                NSLog(@"iPhone storyboard file loaded for iPhone 5 (4inch screen)");
            }
    }

    return YES;
```

Comment: How/where are you creating the UIWindow? And have you removed any storyboard references from the Info.plist?

Comment: @valheru I checked the info.plist and everything seems to be the way it should.  I'll take a screen capture later